# Does GRUB 2.12 now support detached headers?

Tags: grub, luks, header-file

In [GRUB's project status update, at FOSDEM 2022](https://archive.fosdem.org/2022/schedule/event/grub_status_update/attachments/slides/5150/export/events/attachments/grub_status_update/slides/5150/grub_project_status_update_20220119_dk.pdf), they talked about adding detached headers support in GRUB 2.12 (for decryption) :

> Add cryptodisk detached headers and key files support, Denis 'GNUtoo' Carikli, Glenn Washburn,Patrick Steinhardt

GRUB 2.12 was released in December 2023, but I couldn't find any mention of that feature [in its `NEWS` file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/grub/latest/source/NEWS).

Does anybody know if 2.12 now supports detached headers, as initially planned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes. See [GRUB Manual on cryptomount](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#cryptomount).

> cryptomount [-H file]

> The `-H` options can be used to supply cryptomount backends with an alternative header file (aka detached header). Not all backends have headers nor support alternative header files (currently only LUKS1 and LUKS2 support them).

In the Grub console, `help cryptomount` also lists it:

> `-H, --header    Read header from file`

However, the other side is getting this feature integrated in Grub's userspace utilities. In `/etc/default/grub` `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK`, there seems to be no way to specify an external header yet.

So you'd have to jump some hoops to make this work for early cryptomount. It does not work out of the box for an encrypted `/boot` partition and encrypted grub config.

Answer (score 3):

Googling for "cryptodisk detached headers" brings up [this patch from 2022](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2022-06/msg00070.html) which is part of the patch series that was supposed to add support for detached cryptodisk headers.

When viewing the [`cryptodisk.c` of GRUB 2.12](https://elixir.bootlin.com/grub/grub-2.12/source/grub-core/disk/cryptodisk.c), the additions made by that patch seem to be present. So I believe the patch got applied and so the answer is **yes, detached headers are now supported**.

I guess it got lumped into this part of the NEWS file entry:

> ...and tons of other fixes and cleanups...